# Jquery Datatables Serverside better way of column ordering

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am implementing datatables in asp mvc now. I've managed to get it to run and search. However, I am wondering if there is a better way of sorting/ordering? 
Currently I have to manually define my columns and ordering in a dictionary and then do a search for the key and then use the value.

Does datatables have a native method of doing this? I used to use datatables for Codeigniter and I didn't have to do this. Here is my controller and view.

View:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#table").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Users/LoadUsers",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function (d) {

                },
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "ordering": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id", "name": "Id","orderable":false },
                { "data": "Email", "name": "Email" },
                { "data": "UserName", "name": "UserName" },
                { "data": "PhoneNumber", "name": "PhoneNumber" },
            ],
            "processing":true,
            "serverSide": true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadUsers()
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        try
        {
            string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
            string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
            string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
            string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
            int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
            int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);

            var data = dbContext.Users.ToList();
            int totalRecords = data.Count;

            var modelStructure = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            modelStructure.Add(0, "Id");
            modelStructure.Add(1, "Email");
            modelStructure.Add(2, "UserName");
            modelStructure.Add(3, "PhoneNumber");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
            {
                data = data.Where(
                    u => u.UserName.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                    u.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                ).ToList();
            }
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(order) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderDir)))
            {
                var columnName = modelStructure.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == Convert.ToInt32(order));
                data = data.OrderBy(columnName.Value + " " + orderDir).ToList();
            }

            int recFilter = data.Count;
            data = data.Skip(startRec).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            var modifiedData = data.Select(u => new UsersViewModel
            {
                Id = u.Id,
                Email = u.Email,
                UserName = u.UserName,
                PhoneNumber = u.PhoneNumber
            });
            result = this.Json(new
            {
                draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw),
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                recordsFiltered = recFilter,
                data = modifiedData,
                order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]"),
                orderdir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0]
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for native API [`order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) method, or a custom sort/ordering by custom function?

Comment: Hi! I'm looking to see if there is a native API method of converting column ids into column names